# Synchronized Timer on hundreds of Meteor Clients

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Recently, I started developing a sports app using the Meteor platform. The app synchronizes scores of sports matches to connected clients in real-time (currently soccer matches). On each client, the current match time is shown as countdown ([see screenshot of client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OueR3.png)).

The server updates the match time every second and clients subscribe to match+match time. Since the match time is a reactive variable, it needs to be published/subscribed every second. With only a few clients this is not a problem. But if thousands or even hundreds of clients subscribe, it will slow down the server, result in hanging countdowns etc...

I am searching for a proper solution on how to implement a synchronized countdown with Meteor (ideally real-time) that works with a magnitude of connected clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two packages that will be useful for you:

1. [mizzao:timesync](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/timesync) for synchronizing time (like ntp) between clients and the server
2. [remocoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) for creating *reactive* time.

Reactive time happens on the client so it doesn't burden the server. Timesync of course synchronizes both but it doesn't need to run every second.